# How do I uncheck "Don't ask me again and always do the following:" in Send To OneNote tool?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I am running Office 365 on Windows 8.1. When doing a screen clipping in the Send To OneNote Tool the option is given as to which notebook or recent pick I would like to send the screen shot to in OneNote. Then wonderfully when I am doing many such shots back to back there is an option to save some clicks by checking the box for "Don't ask me again and always do the following:" It then skips that screen and sends it straight to where I indicated when I checked the box.

**How do I get back to that screen to change or disable this default Send To destination?** It no longer shows itself so that I can uncheck the box until next time.

I truly need to be able to check it for 20-30 screenshots, then go to a different notebook to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on File and then click on Options.
2. In the OneNote Options window, click on Send to OneNote.
3. Under Other Content, click the drop down for Screen clippings and then select Always ask where to send.
4. Click on OK and then try taking a screen clip to check.

source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/how-to-undo-the-dont-ask-me-again-button-in/abcb2276-a87f-47bf-ab8b-9edfb6b59550